# How do you establish the regularity conditions for the Cramér–Rao lower bound for the sample variance estimator?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, estimators

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n \sim \text{IID } f(\theta)$ be a random sample from a distribution with parameter $\theta$ and let $S^2(\mathbf{x}_n) \equiv \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i -\bar{x}_n)^2$ denote the sample variance. I want to check the regularity conditions for the [Cramér–Rao lower bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound), namely:

$$\begin{align}
&(1) & & \mathbb{V}_\theta(S^2(\mathbf{X}_n))< \infty, \\[10pt]
&(2) & & \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \int S^2 (\mathbf{x}_n) f(\mathbf{x}_n | \theta) \ dx = \int S^2(\mathbf{x}_n) \frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} (\mathbf{x}_n | \theta) \ dx. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

I would say that $(1)$ is obvious, since $S^2$ is finite, but I do not know what to do with $(2)$.  Could you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, condition $(1)$ is not satisfied unless you impose an important moment condition on the distribution of your random variables.  The [variance of the sample variance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/290822/how-to-estimate-variance-of-sample-variance/340943#340943) for IID random variables has a known form, and it is finite if and only if the underlying distribution has finite kurtosis.  So condition $(1)$ is only satisfied if this is the case.

Condition $(2)$ is a condition involving the allowability of bringing the derivative operator inside the integral.  The general rule for derivatives of integrals is given by [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule), and the regularity condition holds in the case where the support of the underlying distribution does not depend on the parameter $\theta$.